# how to tell chrome not to offer suggestions for a text box

Tags: html

Is there a flag you can put on an input element that tells Chrome (or any browser) not to offer suggestions for that input box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `autocomplete` attribute to `off` on the `input` element (see [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-autocomplete)):

```
<input type="text" name="input1" autocomplete="off" />
```

You can also set this attribute on the `form` element itself (see [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#attr-form-autocomplete)).

Answer (score 0):

add the attribute `autocomplete="off"` in the input text